# Cloud function not getting called in REST from Java

Tags: java, parse-platform

I'm trying to call a cloud function from Java through REST but no luck. This is the code:

```
String urlString = "https://api.parse.com/1/functions/hello";
URL url = new URL(urlString); 
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();           

conn.setRequestProperty("X-Parse-Application-Id", "my_app_id"); 
conn.setRequestProperty("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "my_rest_key"); 
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",  String.valueOf(params.getBytes().length));
conn.setRequestMethod("GET"); 
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
```

This code works well for classes queries, but it returns a `fileNotFound` exception when I'm calling it for a function:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.parse.com/1/functions/hello
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1834)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't work. It returns a 404, be sure everything is ok in parse.com (the problem is not in your Java code)

Comment: @MarcoAcierno did you try it with your own app id and rest key, and with the "hello" function present? If so I really hope someone from Parse.com responds here.

Comment: have you tried calling your function using curl, just to make sure the function works normally? https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-calling

Comment: Thanks @ccwasden I used curl now and the function works. So it is something with the java.

Comment: Is this android? Are you using the parse sdk? Supposedly you can use the static method `ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground` if you are using the sdk

Comment: No, not the SDK, I'm trying to make an http call through the generic java api. I'm sure the SDK works perfectly, but there's no SDK for server side java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be a bit late but from what I can see you are issuing a `GET` request...

```
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

however, the REST API explicitly states that Cloud Code functions should be called via a `POST` request.  That is "probably" why you are getting the a 404 exception (File Not Found), because this endpoint does NOT accept `GET` requests. You should set up your `HttpURLConnection` object the following way...

```
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
```

If you look at the `curl` examples below you will see that all request to Cloud Functions use `POST` method

https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-calling

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: 000000000000000000000000000000000000000" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"movie":"The Matrix"}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/functions/averageStars
```

Comment: I don't think that minor detail is documented anywhere in the docs.

Comment: @Genu you're right. The documentation has changed since this question was asked. However, the only two examples in of REST API that uses the Cloud Code platform issue a `POST` request, not a `GET` request